# c++ scoping weirdness - Why do inner-type parameters of member functions do not need scoping?

Tags: c++, member, scoping

Let's say we're given this class with an inner struct.

```
class Some {
   public:
    struct Crap{};
    Crap Process(Crap& c);
}


Some::Crap Some::Process(Crap& crap) {   Crap moreCrap = ..  }
```

It makes sense to me that the return type (Some::Crap) in "Process" is scoped.

It makes sense to me that no scoping is needed inside the body of "Process".

I do not understand why the inner struct parameter of Process (Crap& crap) **does not** require scoping.

Does anyone have any insight on this?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't compile, even if you add the `;` after the class definition and make the function body legal.  Was the original function a member of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the parameter type *does* need to be qualified (unless your example is incorrect and you intend for `Process` to be a member function of `Some`).

Comment: yes, I intended Process to be a member of Some.  fixed.  sorry

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following snippet:

```
class Some
{
public:
    struct Crap{};
    Crap Process(Crap&);
};

Some::Crap Some::Process(Crap& crap) { ... }
```

Basically, `Crap` does not require scoping inside the function parameter list and body for the same reason you don't need `this->` to access data members and member functions: it is implicit because it is at the same scope.

The reason return type is needed is simply because the parser encounters the return type before the method name and cannot (is not required to?) deduce scope at that moment.

Comment: so what you are saying is parser implementation details leaked out into the language syntax?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is "leaked", but the parser and the language syntax obviously go hand in hand.  When designing the syntax, you want to make sure an unambiguous, realizable parser can be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The question title says 'member function', but your example contains no member function.  Assuming you meant `Some::Process` rather than just `Process`:

The class scope for the member function definition begins at the `(`, not at the `{`.  I assume the reasoning is exactly so that things like this can be typed shorter.